# Dynamic pivot in SQL server: insert spaces in concatenation and referencing a pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in long format which I convert to wide format dynamically.

The code was heavily influenced by: [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

```
create table #temp
(
    ID int,
    category varchar(15),
    Answer varchar (5)
)

insert into #temp values ('1', 'breakfast','yes')
insert into #temp values ('1', 'lunch','no')
insert into #temp values ('1', 'dinner','yes')
insert into #temp values ('2', 'breakfast','no')
insert into #temp values ('2', 'lunch', 'yes')
insert into #temp values ('2', 'dinner', 'no')

select * from #temp
```

Which I can convert into wide format:

```
DECLARE @cols  AS VARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(category) + ',' FROM (select distinct category from #temp ) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) 


exec (
'SELECT ID, '+@cols+', concat('+@cols+' )as NewCol from 
(
    select ID, category,answer from #temp
) pivotexample
pivot 
(
    max(Answer) for category in (' + @cols + ')
) as pivotexample2'
) 

drop table #temp
```

The distinct values in the category column can change so I needed a dynamic solution (as above). This give the below pivoted output:

[image]

The issue I have is how can I insert a separator in the concatenation part that creates NewColumn in the pivot.

Also when I then run a `select * from pivotexample2` query, it says Invalid object name 'pivotexample2'. I don't understand why this is, because this is the alias I have given it and want to reference it for things like joins further in the pipeline. How can I give it an alias so I can refence it again? Is it possible to put the pivot within a CTE so I can refence it again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat_ws`:

```
DECLARE @cols  AS VARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(category) + ',' FROM (select distinct category from #temp ) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) 


exec (
'SELECT ID, '+@cols+', concat_ws('','', '+@cols+' )as NewCol from 
(
    select ID, category,answer from #temp
) pivotexample
pivot 
(
    max(Answer) for category in (' + @cols + ')
) as pivotexample2'
) 

drop table #temp
```

It would return:

| ID | breakfast | dinner | lunch | NewCol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | yes | no | yes,yes,no |
| 2 | no | no | yes | no,no,yes |

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45dce502caf3b71662b963fb52dff94e